# Why does the sudoers file contain IP addresses?

Tags: sudo

According to the documentation, modifications of this file may enable local users to execute sudo commands on remote machines:

```
user1 192.168.1.14=(user2:group1) ALL
```

According to what I read, this entry enables `user1` to execute all commands on the host with the IP `192.168.1.14`. How could this be possible?

I also have problems understanding what does running commands as different users means?

Answer (score 2):

From my look at `man 5 sudoers`, this might be intended for the case you distribute or share the same `sudoers` file over several machines, effectively making part of the file conditional on your hostname. So, you still have to have this `sudoers` file on 192.168.1.14, but it would not give you rights on .1.15.